# Sign In with apple in Swift5

Tags: ios, swift5, apple-sign-in

I had implement Sign In with the apple button. It's functionality working. But the issue is its title looks like "**SIGN_IN_WITH_APPLE**" instead of "**Sign in with Apple**". here is my code.

```
let authorizationButton = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton() 
authorizationButton.cornerRadius = 10
authorizationButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLogInWithAppleIDButtonPress), for: .touchUpInside)
cell.signInStack.addArrangedSubview(authorizationButton)
```

And How it's look 
 [image]

Comment: i m facing the same problem . did you find the solution ? kindly share

Comment: No, But I used custom button

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
let button = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton()
print(button.accessibilityLabel ?? "")
```

and it prints

```
Sign in with Apple
```

I am not sure, if you can change it, but

> Automatic translation of the button's title into the language that's
>   set for the device

could explain your trouble, the only way that you can alter the button name is by changing the locale