# Sign in with Apple button title always displays "SIGN_IN_WITH_APPLE"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sign-in-with-apple

I have an app which is localised for two languages: English and Lithuanian. I'm implementing Sign in with Apple functionality and everything is working great except for the button title, which I'm trying to localise.

I'm creating the button as recommended in documentation: `let asiButton = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .signIn, style: .black)` I've entered "SIGN_IN_WITH_APPLE" in `Localizable.strings` for both languages. When the language is set to Lithuanian, the button displays a correct string, but when I change the language to English, the button always displays `SIGN_IN_WITH_APPLE` (as in the screenshot).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrOBa.png)

For some reason it seems to ignore the value I've put into `Localizable.strings` for an English version (although all other strings work as expected), as I can remove it altogether and have the same outcome.

I've tried getting and setting the label to the button directly through code using `asiButton.accessibilityLabel`, but this returns `nil` and setting it results in the same outcome, a button with `SIGN_IN_WITH_APPLE` title.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use *Localizable.strings* for this. ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton is already automatically localized.

Comment: In fact, if you try to set the text of this button yourself, Apple will probably reject the app.

Comment: If I remove it from both Localizable.strings, it still displays "SIGN_IN_WITH_APPLE". Should this be a clue that there's a deeper problem in the implementation of localisation in the app? I was quite confident the implementation is solid, and we didn't have any problems with it in either testing or production. But I guess that's the next suspect to search for clues...

Comment: Yes, you should be seeing the correct title automatically. I’ve never seen it say SIGN_IN_WITH_APPLE like that. I see another question like yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60125468/sign-in-with-apple-in-swift5 But I can’t reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am using `ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton` but it does not get localized in Dutch, when I change my simulator's language to Dutch. Any thoughts? @matt

Comment: @iRiziya I have the same problem. Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same issue.
I added `"SIGN_IN_WITH_APPLE" = "Sign in with Apple";` pair to my `Localizable.strings` that chained to `English` file and all working fine.

It's kinda an answer, but I suppose this message should be in comments. Sorry, but right now I'm not allowed make comment cause of low reputation count.. )